# How can I use php gettext() with jquery mobile?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, gettext

I've been able to use `gettext()` to translate from English to French successfully by using `<?echo __("somestring") ?>` by itself. But I can't figure out how to make `gettext()` work inside of the following jQuery mobile tag:

```
<li><a href="#home" class="ui-btn-active" ><? __("Home")?></a></li>
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The alias for gettext() is a single underscore, not a double underscore.

From the php.net manual for [gettext()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php):

```
// Or use the alias _() for gettext()
echo _("Have a nice day");
```

Comment: I have tried `_e("text") and it causes the rest of the code to be ignored. See this link:
![broken site](http://screencast.com/t/JHXThqe45)

and I have gotten it to work but only with gettext() rather

Comment: I have tried `<li><a href="#home" class="ui-btn-active" ><?php _e("Home"); ?></a></li>`
 and it causes the rest of the code to be ignored.  See this link:
![broken site](http://screencast.com/t/JHXThqe45)

It works correctly with the following:
`<li><a href="#home" class="ui-btn-active" ><?php echo gettext("Home"); ?></a></li>`

See this image:
![good one](http://screencast.com/t/NVFWSlxgTzX)

What's going on with "_e"?

Comment: _e() doesn't exist in PHP. Wordpress does define an _e function. You just need echo _("foo");

Answer (score 0):

In the code above you're not outputting the result of _(). You have: 
`<?php _('foo') ?>` and not `<?php print  _('foo'); ?>`. Is this the case in your real code?